# Use CTE to insert data into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am writing a query in MSSQL.
I am writing a huge logic in CTE, this logic has to be used to insert data into multiple tables.
I dont want to write this CTE for every table, want it to be generic for every table.

Example:

```sql
with CTE as (Select * from table)
select * into table3 from table1 join cte
select * into table4 from table2 join cte
```

is it possible to achieve it

I tried to write the insert statement and tried to use the same CTE in generic way

Comment: You could instead dump the results of {cte} into a {#temp table}. If you only need to insert the rows into _two_ tables, you could perhaps use `WITH cte AS () INSERT dbo.table1 OUTPUT inserted.cols INTO dbo.table2 SELECT FROM cte;`.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE must be complied immediately before using it in your subsequent SQL to do the insert. Have you considered creating a VIEW instead of a CTE? That way you could re-use the logic over and over again without having to repeat the CTE each time.